# Printing unicode character

Tags: php, unicode, currency

**₹**

```
HTML Entity (decimal)   &#8377;
HTML Entity (hex)   &#x20b9;
How to type in Microsoft Windows    Alt +20B9
UTF-8 (hex) 0xE2 0x82 0xB9 (e282b9)
UTF-8 (binary)  11100010:10000010:10111001
UTF-16 (hex)    0x20B9 (20b9)
UTF-16 (decimal)    8,377
UTF-32 (hex)    0x000020B9 (20b9)
UTF-32 (decimal)    8,377
```

I need to print this char, I'm doing this:

```
$str = htmlentities('&#8377');
echo html_entity_decode($str);
```

but it just outputs `&#8377`. I'm expecting the char `₹`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it:

`echo html_entity_decode('&#8377;', ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');`

Answer (score 2):

A character reference like `&#8377;` is not recognized without the trailing semicolon. Moreover, you can simply use

```
echo "&#8377;"
```

or (if you are properly using UTF-8 throughout, which is recommendable) simply

```
echo "₹";
```

And quite often you don’t need `echo`, as you can simply write the reference `&#8377;` or the character `₹` in HTML.

Whether browsers render the “₹” character is a different issue; you should normally do some font settings, possibly with a downloadable font, `@font-face`.

Comment: hmm.. nothing works. I'm trying to replace "Rs" with this symbol in a file like this: http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/i18n/data/en.dat

Comment: @3zzy, whatever problems you have with that file, they are quite different from the question you asked (and even answered yourself). So it should be posted as a new question, with sufficient detail. If this is about replacing a quoted string by a quoted character in JSON data, as it seems, make sure you state this clearly, specify the character encoding(s) that is used or can be used, and describe whether this is a one-time replacement (hence probably off-topic at SO) or something to be done programmatically (in which language?).

Comment: Its a one-time replacement, but probably useful for every indian because `Rs` needs to be replaced by `₹` sooner or later.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "&#x20B9;";
```

Works as long as you are outputting to HTML content, where character references apply. No good for other formats (eg injecting into JavaScript).

```
echo "₹";
```

Will work fine as long as your source file is saved in UTF-8 encoding.

Otherwise, the UTF-8 byte encoding of character U+20B9 Indian Rupee Sign is 0xE2, 0x82, 0xB9. So:

```
echo "\xE2\x82\xB9";
```

Or, using a function to create UTF-8 strings from code point numbers:

```
function unichr($i) {
    return iconv('UCS-4LE', 'UTF-8', pack('V', $i));
}

echo unichr(0x20B9);
```

Comment: I'm trying to replace `Rs` with this char in http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/i18n/data/en.dat but nothing seems to work

Comment: @3zzy: Post the code you're using to try to do the replacement. The `echo` works fine.

Comment: That exact file: http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/i18n/data/en.dat

Comment: That's a data file in PHP serialize() format. Are you trying to write code to alter it? If so use a plain old `str_replace`. If you are trying to alter the data file manually, then this is not a programming question. But as long as you have a text editor that supports UTF-8 (eg Notepad++), it should be trivially easy to load the file into it, replace `s:2:"Rs";` with `s:3:"₹"` and save it.

Comment: I'm trying to manually edit the file, and I did try replacing `Rs` with `₹` but it still shows `Rs`